# Reduce volumes for specific domain during IP warmup

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, ip-warming

I need to do an IP address warm up for gmail domain. I already know that the maximun send for gmail is 5,000 records per day. What I need to know is: how can I segment the DE incrementing the number of records week by week until I reach the total of records? There is a query peraphs?

I already tried to research documentation online, but I only found tables for the warm up (I don't need that, because I already divided the records in a table in order to undestand the timing for the warm up).

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Let me know if my answer was helpful, and don't forget to mark it as accepted if it was.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would divide your entire base, and not only particular email domains. As long as the sends to individual email domains don't exceed the recommended limit.

You can use this query in Query Studio to verify the number of recipients with each domain:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1000 RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)) as domain,
COUNT(email) as domain_count
FROM   Contacts
WHERE  LEN(email) > 0
GROUP BY RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))
ORDER BY domain_count DESC
```

Where *Contacts* is the data extension with your recipients and *email* is your email field.

[Adam Spriggs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) explains in his post here, how you can work with SQL for creating random segments of your data extension for the IP warmup: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/121976/36623

You can increase the number in select statement to increase the size of your subsequent segments:

```sql
select distinct top 5000
```

However, IP warmup is never straightforward. You need to take following precautions:

- Are you sending from another system today? In that case, you need to ensure you keep sending some of the emails from here, and some from MC. You need to manage that your full list will be sent to, without anyone receiving two emails.
- Are you sure, you are on a private IP address? Shared IP addresses don't require IP warmup.
- When calculating limits for Microsoft domains, you need to add numbers for Hotmail.com, Live.com, Outlook.com and Msn.com domains.